# Difference between WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT and CHECK CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

What is the difference between these scripts?

```
ALTER TABLE Post_Send WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [My_FOREIGN_KEY];  
GO

ALTER TABLE Post_Send CHECK CONSTRAINT [My_FOREIGN_KEY];
GO
```

Comment: They're showing the same effect.

Answer (score 13):

`CHECK CONSTRAINT` enables a constraint. (Yes, it should have been `ENABLE` instead.) `WITH NOCHECK` does so without checking existing data. So the confusing syntax `WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT` enables a constraint without checking existing data.

From [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql):

> Specifies whether the data in the table is or is not validated against
>   a newly added or re-enabled `FOREIGN KEY` or `CHECK` constraint. If not
>   specified, `WITH CHECK` is assumed for new constraints, and `WITH NOCHECK`
>   is assumed for re-enabled constraints.

Since you're re-enabling an existing constraint, `WITH NOCHECK` is the default, and these two statements do exactly the same thing. `WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT` would re-enable the constraint while also checking existing data for violations (and marking the foreign key as trusted for optimizations in the process, which doesn't happen if you bypass the check).